# Request Fail error in Angular Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension using AngularJS. I'm trying make a $http.get() request which works fine in normal HTML pages, but failing to do so in my extension saying a **500 (Request Failed)** error. Here's my manifest

```
{
    "name": "The Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "A extension for chrome browsers",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

My app.js (loaded from background.js):

```
//This is adding base directive in app
var app = '<div class="my-extension"><div base></div></div>';
var wrapper = '<div ng-non-bindable>' + app + '</div>';
$('body').append(wrapper);
var myExtension = angular.module('my-extension', ['baseModule']);

window.name = '';
angular.bootstrap($('.my-extension')[0], ['my-extension']);
```

And base is:

```
var baseModule = angular.module('baseModule', []);
baseModule.directive('base', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>Hello World</div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://api.example.com/api/yy/zz' //Sample API, Data is being got surely
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('success', response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('error', response);
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```

Pardon me if the question is silly, I'm relatively super new in Extension development.

Comment: I have it set for all urls @wOxxOm, see my manifest. I guest that should cover it all

Comment: Permission works for the extension pages, not for content scripts or injected scripts. Where's that code?

Answer (score 0):

In [HTTP Status and Error Codes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#500_Internal_Server_Error), an error 500 means there's an Internal Server Error which can be caused by either backendError or an internalError.

To help you troubleshoot the problem, you may try the following as given in this [post](https://www.reference.com/technology/fix-http-500-internal-server-error-a7910c61e9123f0e):

- clear the browser's cache and cookies, restart the browser and try to reload the page.
- check for any incorrect permissions in the site's configuration, reconfigure timeout rules and check whether the website's .htaccess file is correct.